# Swipedector on entire screen flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

We are using the swipedetector: ^1.2.0 plugin for flutter, I have it working for swipe up and I wrapped it around a container at the bottom of the screen.

### EDIT

I was able to wrap the entire column in SwipeDetector but its not working now. No errors. I'm not sure if SwipeDetector needs to be inside of a column instead of outside. When I swipe right on any part of the emulator screen it doesnt fire even when I set a breakpoint.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
return new Scaffold(
     appBar : LBAppBar().getAppBar(),
      //drawer: new LBDrawer().getDrawer(),
     body:  Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: new LinearGradient(
            colors: [Color.fromRGBO(1,89,99, 1.0), Colors.grey],
            begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            end: Alignment.topRight
        )
    ),
     child: 
     SwipeDetector(
         onSwipeRight: () {
           Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new WidgetsPage())
            ); },
      child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,    
      children:[
        Row(
                children: [
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0,top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right:30.0),
                child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[



                Text("Hi ${user.firstName}, Today is " + formatDate(), style: new TextStyle( color: Colors.white70, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 19.0 
     )),




        ],

         ),
                  ),
                   ]
            ),

          Row(
            //ROW 1
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0,top: 60.0, bottom: 30.0, right:30.0),
                child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
           GestureDetector(
                     child: Icon(
                     FontAwesomeIcons.checkSquare,
                     size: 50.0,
                     color: Colors.white70,
             ),
                  onTap: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new CheckIn()));
                          }),
                Text("Check In", style: new TextStyle( color: Colors.white70, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal ))
  ],
 ),
              ),
              Container(
               margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0,top: 60.0, bottom: 30.0, right:30.0),
                child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
           GestureDetector(

                     child: Icon(
                     FontAwesomeIcons.list,
                     size: 50.0,
                      color: Colors.white70,
             ),
                  onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new DayAtAGlance()));
                          }),
                Text("My Day", style: new TextStyle( color: Colors.white70, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal ))
],
 ),
                ),
            Container(
               margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0,top: 60.0, bottom: 30.0, right:30.0),
                child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
           GestureDetector(
                     child: Icon(
                     FontAwesomeIcons.phone,
                     size: 45.0,
                      color: Colors.white70,
             ),
                  onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new CommunicationLinks()));
                          }),
                  Text("Communication", style: new TextStyle( color: Colors.white70, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal ))
  ],
),
                 ),
                 ]
                  ),
             Row(//ROW 2
              children: [
            Container(
               margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 32.0,top: 50.0, bottom: 30.0),
                child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
           GestureDetector(
                     child: Icon(
                     FontAwesomeIcons.dollarSign,
                     size: 50.0,
                      color: Colors.white70,
               ),
                  onTap: () {
                       Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new Budget()));
                          }),
                Text("Budget", style: new TextStyle( color: Colors.white70, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal ))
],
 ),

                  ),
            Container(
               margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 75.0, top: 50.0, bottom: 30.0, right: 30.0),
                child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
           GestureDetector(
                     child: Icon(
                     FontAwesomeIcons.trophy,
                     size: 50.0,
                      color:  Colors.white70,
             ),
                  onTap: () {
                        print("Pressed");
                          }),
                Text("Goals", style: new TextStyle( color:  Colors.white70, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal ))
],
),

                ),
             Container(
               margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0, top: 50.0, bottom: 30.0, right: 20.0),
                child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
           GestureDetector(
                     child: Icon(
                     FontAwesomeIcons.calendar,
                     size: 50.0,
                      color: Colors.white70,
             ),
                  onTap: () {

                       Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new CalendarsPage()));
                          }),
                Text("Calendar", style: new TextStyle( color: Colors.white70, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal ))
  ],
),
                )
             ]),
          Row(// ROW 3
              children: [
            Container(
               margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, top: 50.0, bottom: 30.0, right: 30.0),
                child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
           GestureDetector(
                     child: Icon(
                     FontAwesomeIcons.comments,
                     size: 50.0,
                      color: Colors.white70,
             ),
                  onTap: () {
                        print("Pressed");
                          }),
                Text("Community", style: new TextStyle( color: Colors.white70, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal ))
  ],
),

                ),
            Container(
               margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 50.0, bottom: 30.0, right: 20.0),
                child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
           GestureDetector(
                     child: Icon(
                     FontAwesomeIcons.shoppingCart,
                     size: 50.0,
                     color: Colors.white70,
             ),
                  onTap: () {
                         Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new ShoppingList()));
                          }),
                Text("Shopping", style: new TextStyle( color: Colors.white70, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal ))
  ],
),

                  ),
              Container(
               margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0, top: 50.0, bottom: 30.0, right: 40.0),
                child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
           GestureDetector(
                     child: Icon(
                     FontAwesomeIcons.solidCheckSquare,
                     size: 50.0,
                      color: Colors.white70,
             ),
                  onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new CheckOut()));
                          }),
                Text("Check Out", style: new TextStyle( color: Colors.white70, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold ))
],
),

                ),
          ]),
        ],
          ),
       )
      //here


     )


   );



 }}
```

Comment: Hi, please provide the source code that is producing the syntax errors - without this, it will not be possible for the community to help you debug your problem. Thanks.

Comment: There is no code, I tried wrapping my main container in Swipedetector  and it doesnt allow it. Only if I do it like I did in my example which isnt the entire screen.

Comment: Can you tell us exactly how you configured Swipedetector? The community has to be able to replicate a problem before we can help you fix it.

Comment: I edited it and added the code.

Comment: Im still having this issue. onSwipeRight is not working.